# Image Processing - Beaglebone vs Raspberry Pi

Tags: image-processing, camera, raspberry-pi, microcontroller, beagleboneblack

I've been researching for a while and found tons of helpful resources on this subject, but I figured I would lay down my specifications here so I can get some recommendations from people experienced in this area. It seems like Beaglebone and Raspberry Pi with a Logitech or Microsoft camera are my best options at this point.

My target speed is 50 fps (20 ms per image) with the processing involved. From what I've looked at, this doesn't seem feasible considering most webcams don't go much past 30 fps. More specifically, I need to take the endpoints of an object (like a sheet of paper) and calculate where the midpoint is. Nothing incredibly fancy. 1080p isn't a requirement, I can most likely go much lower. Python is preferable over C and C++ since I've already done a lot of image processing with Python.

It looks like a lot of the code I'll be needing is mostly open-source already, so I really just need to figure out what controller/camera combo I should be using.

Answer (score 3):

It's still a bit of a toss up between the two however here are my views.

The BBB will use a USB web cam and that will take a certain amount of processing power just to get the image. After that you can then manipulate it with SimpleCV

The RPi has a camera board that they say will only use < 3% of the cpu and the rest can be used for processing your image. Plus you can over-clock the RPi to 1Ghz.

Using the RPi with a basic webcam does not give a very good result, whereas the RPi camera works directly on the CSI bus and is set to do 1080 dpi natively. Plus they now have drivers for the camera that work with SimpleCV too.

IMHO I would say that the RPi B and Camera board would be technically faster that the BBB, but it also depends on what manipulation you plan to do :

Marc